# Remove v from [powershell-vX.0] tag family

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

PowerShell related tags for some reason contain a **v** in their name:

- [powershell-v1.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v1.0)
- [powershell-v2.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v2.0)
- [powershell-v3.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v3.0)
- [powershell-v4.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v4.0)

Please remove it because this breaks our naming convention for versions, which never contain a **v**. Consider the following tags:

- [c#-4.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0)
- [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0)
- [java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7)
- [twitter-bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: v means "version" , powershell-v1.0 = powershell version1.0

Comment: @BGS Yeah, but consider our other naming conventions: [tag:java-7], [tag:.net-4.0], [tag:c#-4.0], [tag:twitter-bootstrap-3], etc. None of those have a ***v*** before the version number. That's the issue here, I think.

Comment: @abatischev I went ahead and added the example of the convention other tags use to your request. Is that OK?

Comment: I don't think the convention you're referring to actually exists. We have `[html5]`, `[css3]` and `[ios5]`, for example. This doesn't seem like it'll cause any confusion about how to tag questions properly, either. Since there is consistency within the PowerShell version tags -- unlike [the IIS tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209701/add-hyphen-to-iis-tag-family) -- I don't see the need to make any changes.

Comment: @Pops CSS3 and HTML5 are, at least, the exact name for the product. It isn't _CSS 3_, for instance - there isn't a space.

Comment: @Pops: In case of HTML5 and CSS3 the number is part of brand/trademark/etc. (Can't say much about iOS x though). The naming convention I'm talking here is not about having hyphen. But not having `v` before version number.

Comment: @Pops: Please review your opinion basing on the comments above.

Comment: I have seen the comments and still do not feel like further action is necessary. While I didn't pick the best example tags, the fact is that there is no official rule or even well-adhered-to convention about version numbering.