# Add hyphen to [IIS] tag family

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

A paradox with IIS related tags is that [iis-7.5](/questions/tagged/iis-7.5) has a hyphen. What is definitely good and follows the naming convention, see [.net-4.5](/questions/tagged/.net-4.5) for instance.

But other don't:

- [iis5](/questions/tagged/iis5)
- [iis6](/questions/tagged/iis6)
- [iis7](/questions/tagged/iis7)
- [iis8](/questions/tagged/iis8)

Please add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the naming convention you're referring to actually exists. We have [html5](/questions/tagged/html5), [css3](/questions/tagged/css3), [ios5](/questions/tagged/ios5), [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2) and more. And I don't think there's a real problem of people being confused about how to tag their IIS questions.

But, that inconsistency bothers me now that you've pointed it out, so, okay. I edited to make all the IIS version tags consistently use hyphens.

Comment: Consistency is the number one bothering me, too. Thank you!